# LINQ datarow string to array and then into to string list

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code that will loop over `DataRow`s and will split a pipe delimited column in the `DataRow` into an array, and then into a `List<string>`.

Is there a better way to do this using LINQ? I've tried but got nowhere!

```
List<string> allSizes = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow resultRow in results.Rows)
{
    if (resultRow["Sizes"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        string[] sizes = resultRow["Sizes"].ToString().Split('|');
        foreach (string size in sizes)
        {
            if (!allSizes.Contains(size))
            {
                allSizes.Add(size);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using `Contains` on a List isn't particularly efficient.  Considering that it's likely that the data set could get large, and you check whether it's in the list or not for each item, that could get expensive.  It's better to use a set-based data structure to perform a `Distinct`, which is what you're doing, and what the LINQ `Distinct` method does.

Answer (score 10):

```
var allSizes = results.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(row => row["Sizes"] != DBNull.Value)
    .SelectMany(row => row["Sizes"].ToString().Split('|'))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Extension methods look much better :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the LINQ version but personally I don't find it much cleaner:

```
var allSizes = new List<string>();

foreach (
    string size in 
    from DataRow resultRow in results.Rows 
    where resultRow["Sizes"] != DBNull.Value 
    select resultRow["Sizes"].ToString().Split('|') into sizes 
    from size in sizes where !allSizes.Contains(size) 
    select size) {
    allSizes.Add(size);
}
```

Comment: As noted to OP, performing a contains on a `List` of nontrivial size isn't a cheap operation; you should be putting the items into a set-based data structure to perform the distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
var linqSizes =
    from row in results.Rows
    where row["Sizes"] != DBNull.Value
    let sizes = row["Sizes"].ToString().Split('|')
    from size in sizes
    group size by size into g
    select g.Key;
```

The variable `linqSizes` will contain the same elements as your variable `allSizes`.

Answer (score 0):

Strong-typed DataRow and LINQ:

```
dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Where(r => r["Sizes"] != DBNull.Value)
      .SelectMany(r=>r.Field<string>("Sizes").Split('|')
      .Distinct().ToList();
```